# Have 1920x1200 and 1024x1280 monitors combined to 2944x1200. How to use the 80 unused lines of screen area on the 1024x1280?

Tags: x11, xrandr, resolution, multi-monitor

The left monitor native resolution is 1920x1200 in landscape mode.
The right monitor native resolution is 1280x1024 but rotated to portrait mode, so 1024x1280.
Because the mouse would get trapped in the bottom 80 lines on the 1024x1280, i cut the bottom 80 lines out of the display port, so the extended desktop resolution is (1920+1024) x 1200 = 2944x1200.

Is there someway i could use the bottom 1024x80 lines as a place that tails out dmesg or /var/log/something?

Comment: You might try not cutting that space and running conky in panel mode there if that is possible.

Comment: Prefer cutting the extra space because it is easier for all users of the machine to not have a "mouse trap" in that space not contiguous with the other monitor.  Would not have to be interactive data, just output.

Comment: :D ghouls are real.
Perhaps an x11 program could be written which opens a window in the particular coordinates and warps the mouse away when it receives a mouse over event.

Comment: That is an idea.  I was thinking there must be something built-in for this purpose.   Even a text only tty would suffice.